# WSOD while using Boost after upgrading to Apache 2.4.6

Tags: 7, caching, wsod

I was using Boost module with Drupal 7 for a few months and all was working fine.

I recently upgraded to Apache 2.4.6 and noticed that Drupal frontpage has white screen.

I disabled Boost and uninstalled it and the site worked fine after that.  Then reinstalled Boost and it was generating cache but the frontpage was WSOD again.

Any idea what could be causing this and/or how to fix?

Comment: have tried clear the cache and also try to remove the cache folder created by boot module. before that take backup.

Comment: I have the following cache folder:public_html/cache/normal, do I delete the whole cache folder?

Comment: Don't delete just rename the cache folder name to something and then clear the cache.

Comment: What's in your Apache's error log? That's the first thing we need to know in cases like that.

Answer (score 0):

check by putting this code in you index.php.

**strong text**

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
include("file_with_errors.php");

this will tell you what is happening, or you can also check in your Watchdog.